# Получить иконку процесса

Tags: c#

Привет.

Сделал инжектор длл в процесс. 
Теперь хочу сделать, чтобы когда находился процесс, то показывалась его иконка.

Вот код:

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("Game");
        if (processesByName.Length > 0)
        {
            PrivilegeManager.InjectDLL(processesByName[0], this.dll_name);
            MessageBox.Show("Чит запущен,Свернуть-Развернуть меню чита на кнопку Home!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Запусти игру!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
```

Пытался через определение, потом вывод, но не получилось, даже не дошло, как начать реализацию!

Comment: [Специально для вас](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%EE%F7%EA%E0_(%E7%ED%E0%EA_%EF%F0%E5%EF%E8%ED%E0%ED%E8%FF))

Comment: @Егор Глухов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Писал на скорою руку, извините за ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить иконку файла традиционным способом, используйте Shell Image List: `SHGetFileInfo`, `SHGetImageList` и иже. В Vista+ используйте `IShellItemImageFactory`.

[Примеры кода на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12470766/293099). Код на C++, для C# понадобится обернуть его интеропом, в самом фреймворке нужных обёрток нет.

**[ правка ]** А, вот, нашёл на C#: [Extract thumbnail for any file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21752100/293099). Ещё есть [Windows API Code Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665/293099), там это тоже есть.

P.S. Не надо ковыряться в ресурсах вручную, как советует @0xFFh, всё уже реализовано до нас.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, получить путь к главному модулю процесса (exe-сборке):

```
Process myProcess = ...
String exe = myProcess.MainModule.FileName;
```

Далее, т.к. это PE-файл со свойственной ему структурой данных, выделить иконку непосредственно из него. **[Вот тут](http://vec3.ca/extracting-icons-from-pe-files/)**, вроде бы, описано довольно неплохо, как это можно сделать.